# "the universe" and "a universe"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following passage, the word "universe" appears four times.
The second one has "a" as its article, while the others have "the".
Am I right in thinking that "a universe" in the passage means an interpretation of "the universe" that people had based on the scientific discoveries.

> Today we have discovered a powerful and elegant way to understand **the** universe, a method called science; it has revealed to us **a** universe so ancient and vast that human affairs seem at first sight to be of little consequence. We have grown distant from the cosmos -- it has seemed remote from every day concerns. But science has found not only that **the** universe is accessible to human understanding, but also that we are, in a very profound sense, a part of that Cosmos, born from it, our fate connected with it. The most basic human events and the most trivial can be traced back to **the** universe and its origins.

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: The word **universe** appears four times in the passage, three with **the** and one with **a**. As you said *a universe* is an interpretation of *the universe*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your interpretation is correct. There may be any number of interpretations about 'the universe' but each one is *a* single interpretation.

*The* universe is the concrete idea about the objective universe.

*A* universe on the other hand refers to an individual subjective interpretation concerning *the* abstract universe.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right in thinking that "a universe" in the passage means an
>   interpretation of "the universe" that people had based on the
>   scientific discoveries.

A better way to put it is that it *classifies* the universe. The indefinite article is "[*used to indicate membership of a class of people or things*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a): ‘he is a lawyer’; ‘this car is a BMW’".

What *kind* of universe is this universe? It is a universe so ancient ... - in contrast to other universes of another kind.

Answer (score -1):

I opened the box and found **an** apple.

Lifting the lid of the box revealed **an** apple.

I took a bite out of **the** apple.

We use the definite article (*the*) to talk about a specific member of a set of similar objects or concepts.  Before things have become specific, i.e. when we first make mention of the object or concept, we need to use the indefinite article (*a/an*).

In short, your explanation does not hold water for me.